# checking android os using javascript not working in uc browser

Tags: android, browser

in this code, i have tried to detect android browser  and then redirect to another page. Its working fine in all mobile browser except “uc browser “ what will be code I have to add in this

```
var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var isAndroid = ua.indexOf("android") > -1; //&& ua.indexOf("mobile");
if(isAndroid)
{
if (window.confirm("hi !!"))
{
window.location.href = "www.google.com"
}
}
```

Comment: checked on ucbrowser 9.7 should be fine